# Reading a variable as another type

Tags: c++

What I am trying to do is take the bits stored from a variable and basically read them as if they were in another.

Say I have an int named *temp* that is worth 10 (1010 in binary).
I would like to be able read it as say an array of bools, giving me [0] = 1, [1] = 0, [2] = 1, [3] = 0, etc. (I would probably get lots of 0 in front in fact, due to the size of an int but meh, it's just an example.)

I have tried making a pointer of the desired type, assigning it to the address of the int but with no success. I have also looked on google but it seems I don't know the name of this practice since I couldn't find anything relevant.

Edit: In pseudo-code, my goal would look something like this.

```
variable _t_'s bytes are equal to 1001010101000111.

if the last 4 bytes are equal to 0111: do stuff.

if the first 4 bytes are equal to 0000: do some more stuff.

etc.
```

Comment: I suppose a [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) is off the table?

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to use those bits as the bits of another type (like `float` or a pointer), or is it just to read and directly use the individual bits?

Comment: @Sneftel, I am ultimately trying to use this to make a basic genetic algorithm.

Comment: @Volvary That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Sneftel The edit in the main post should tell a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

For your particular example you can use `std::bitset`, e.g.:

```
#include <bitset>

int n = 10;
std::bitset<32> s(n);
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a17ba71d45105e03)

Comment: What does the 's' do? Since I am getting an error if I put it.

Comment: `s` is just the name of the variable. Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a17ba71d45105e03

Comment: And would there be a way to read a chunk of it as say an integer? (You can read my comment on the original question to see why I would want to do this.)

Comment: Your question is very vague and unclear - you should probably add some concrete examples of exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Edited the original post to be more precise

Comment: It's still not very clear, but it seems that you might just want to do the kind of low level bitwise stuff that @Juster describes in his answer. In which case, read up on bitwise operators.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is just using bitwise operators: & |. For example:

```
#define FLAG_IS_ALIVE 0x1;
#define FLAG_IS_DANGEROUS 0x2;
#define FLAG_IS_TOUCHABLE 0x4;
#define FLAG_IS_FLUFFY 0x8;
#define FLAG_CAN_BARK 0x10;
...

int kittenFlags = FLAG_IS_ALIVE | FLAG_IS_FLUFFY;
int doggyFlags = FLAG_IS_ALIVE | FLAG_IS_DANGEROUS | FLAG_CAN_BARK;

int someFlags = ...;
if (someFlags & FLAG_IS_FLUFFY && !(someFlags & FLAG_IS_DANGEROUS))
{
    stroke(); cuddle();
}
```